# MOSS Publishing pages and WSS Pages

Tags: sharepoint, moss, master-pages

Can anyone tell me why a masterpage applied to a MOSS publishing site does not get applied to any non publishing pages within the same site - very strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Because a masterpage intended for publishing sites has some controls on it that won't work with regular pages, sharepoint autmatically reverts back to the default.master